# background-color is not working with div

Tags: css, html, background-color

I am trying to set background-color for div element "High Tatras" "High Tatras 2"...elements to yellow with css.

`gallery li {background-color: yellow;}`

jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/pragnesh/CjDDB/

But background-color yellow only applied to top and bottom part of element.

What could be problem with this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jquery-ui seems to have a <strike>weird multiple background css rule</strike> (lol it's not a multiple background... just the comments threw me off... it's late).  Try using just the background attribute instead:

```
.gallery li {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j2TtX/

The rule that is causing the background is this one:

```
.ui-widget-content { 
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorContent}*/;
    background: #ffffff/*{bgColorContent}*/ url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)/*{bgImgUrlContent}*/ 50%/*{bgContentXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgContentYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgContentRepeat}*/;
    color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a white color background image in the jquery UI-library, add this line in your CSS to overwrite the css rule.

```
.gallery li.ui-widget-content{background-image:none;}​
```

Comment: This would be more correct than my blunt approach of overriding the whole background deceleration.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Overrating this background that is the issue , You should remove background property in this class ".ui-widget-content"

```
.ui-widget-content {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    color: #222222;
}
```

It comes from jquery-ui.css (line 243)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/CjDDB/4/)

Problem is once you set the `background-image` for a div then you can not override it via `background-color` because it only set only color property(which has low priority than image) while `background` property will reset all background related properties i.e,

1. background-color
2. background-image
3. background-position
4. background-repeat
5. background-attachment

and set the color. So use:

```
 background: yellow;
```